# Divisão de base em treino e teste no R

Tags: r

Tenho uma base de dados, onde a minha variável `resposta` são datas e a explicativa é a vazão da fonte de uma cidade.

Gerei um modelo de série temporal, como forma de tentar entender o quão confiável eram meus dados, porém, a medida AIC não é uma medida tão eficaz para tal.

A ideia era dividir minha base em treino e teste e tentar fazer uma previsão dos dados, o que ajudaria a ter mais certeza de confiabilidade. Meus dados são:

```
Data       Fonte Férrea
jan/18     160,11
fev/18     NA
mar/18     150,88
abr/18     NA
mai/18     127,52
jun/18     171,25
jul/18     111,24
ago/18     111,26
set/18     109,79
out/18     295,12
nov/18     361
dez/18     365
jan/19     118,29
fev/19     112,18
mar/19     204,4
abr/19     109,95
mai/19     122,93
jun/19     130,43
jul/19     80,33
ago/19     96,52
set/19     83,46
out/19     101,71
nov/19     58,63
dez/19     119,67
jan/20     136,61
```

A dúvida é: como dividir esses dados em treino e teste?

A ideia era deixar as últimas 4 observações na base teste e o restante na treino, porém, não sei como colocar na função do R as últimas 4 observações, sendo elas de out/19 a jan/20.

A função do R que gera os dados de treino e teste é:

```
treino=window(basededados,end=)
teste=window(basededados,start=,end=)
```

Comment: A variável resposta é a data mesmo? O teu objetivo é prever a data futura em função da vazão? Além disso, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: A variável resposta é a data. Meu objetivo é fazer a previsão dos dados. Para isso, to dividindo minha base em treino e teste. Só que não consegui entender como colocar na função window uma data de início e fim quando os dados de data são dados em mês/ano.

Comment: Tem certeza disso? Por favor, explique então o que significa "fazer a previsão dos dados". É prever as datas futuras? Ou prever o valor da vazão nas datas futuras? Porque se for o segundo caso, a variável resposta é a vazão. Além disso, compartilhe os dados de acordo com o link que passei acima, para ficar mais fácil de te auxiliarmos.

Comment: A previsão dos dados aqui no caso, é só para fornecer uma indicação confiável de quão bom é o modelo para prever novos dados, é mais para uma questão de confiabilidade. Minha variável resposta é a data, pq eu quero saber como a vazão é explicada com o passar do tempo. A dificuldade aqui, no caso, é como fazer a divisão da base que to usando em treino e teste, pois minha data é colocada da forma mês/ano. Não entendi como colocar na função window para que possa ler de forma correta.

Comment: `i <- 1:(ncol(dados) - 4);train <- dados[i, ];test <- dados[-i, ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar as função `head` e `tail` para escolher as observações.

Segue forma de reproduzir os dados da pergunta:

```
dados <- tibble::tribble(
 ~Data, ~Fonte_Férrea,
 "jan/18", 160.11,
 "fev/18", NA,
 "mar/18", 150.88,
 "abr/18", NA,
 "mai/18", 127.52,
 "jun/18", 171.25,
 "jul/18", 111.24,
 "ago/18", 111.26,
 "set/18", 109.79,
 "out/18", 295.12,
 "nov/18", 361,
 "dez/18", 365,
 "jan/19", 118.29,
 "fev/19", 112.18,
 "mar/19", 204.4,
 "abr/19", 109.95,
 "mai/19", 122.93,
 "jun/19", 130.43,
 "jul/19", 80.33,
 "ago/19", 96.52,
 "set/19", 83.46,
 "out/19", 101.71,
 "nov/19", 58.63,
 "dez/19", 119.67,
 "jan/20", 136.61)
```

E então basta definir quantas observações quer na base de treino, digamos `4`, e criar os objetos.

```
n <- 4
treino <- head(dados, -n)
teste <- tail(dados, n)
```

Caso queira algo mais elaborado e estruturado para ligar com modelos, recomendo dar uma olhada no pacote [recipes](https://tidymodels.github.io/recipes/articles/Simple_Example.html) ([recipes](/questions/tagged/recipes)).